# Arduino2max digital pin communication to max using an Arduino mega 2560

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino, max, max-msp-jitter

Im working on connecting an Arduino Mega 2560 into max msp, I have adapted the Arduino2max arduino code and max patch.

I have adapted the max patch and succeeded with all 16 analog inputs from arduino into max but cannot get any digital pins over number 13 into max msp. I was wondering if anyone had had any sucsess with this?

Any help and comments would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Joe

here is the arduino code adapted from Arduino2max v.5 which can be found here http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/MaxMSP

```
int x = 0;              
int ledpin = 13;

void setup ()
{
// 115200 is the default Arduino Bluetooth speed
Serial.begin(115200);
///startup blink
digitalWrite(13,HIGH);              
delay(600);
digitalWrite(13,LOW);
pinMode(13,INPUT);
}



void loop()
{ 
// Check serial buffer for characters
if (Serial.available() > 0){  
if (1){     //Serial.read() == 'r') { // If an 'r' is received then read the pins 
// Read and send analog pins 0-15
for (int pin= 0; pin<=15; pin++)
{ 
 x = analogRead(pin);
 sendValue (x);
}

// Read and send digital pins 2-53
for (int pin= 2; pin<=53; pin++)

{         
 x = digitalRead(pin);
 sendValue (x);
}

 // Send a carriage return to mark end of pin data.
    Serial.println(); 
 // add a delay to prevent crashing/overloading of the serial port
delay (5);                        
 }
}
}
// function to send the pin value followed by a "space".
void sendValue (int x){ 
 Serial.print(x);
 Serial.print(32, BYTE);
 }
```

Thanks again!

Comment: The article at that link says "Arduino2Max is a Max patch with accompanying Arduino code that allows you to read the Arduino's 12 digital and 6 analog pins in Max/MSP." Which corresponds to an entire Arduino, so why do you think it can handle more than that?

Comment: You might have to hack on the Arduino2Max host PC side to get more values. Would you feel confident enough to attempt that?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am using a mega 2560 board with 16 analog inputs and 54 digital. So far I have been able to receive all 16 analog inputs but only 12 digital inputs into max

Comment: So some success but still no extra digital :(. Confident yes, knowledgeable no. What do you mean by hacking the arduino2max pc side?  Any other methods or suggestions are more than appreciated and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I looked at the original code, and your code for the Arduino side. AFAICT, each sensor or digital pin is sent as a number followed by a space (`Serial.print(32, BYTE);`), then a carriage return (`Serial.println();`) after sending all the sensors/digital pins. So the program on the PC side needs to be able to receive as many different sensor/input values as the Arduino sends. Does that make sense? So if it gives up at 28 (16+12), then maybe someone needs to go look at the host PC program, find the code which receives the sensor values, and see how to extend that number of values.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense so it will be producing more values than the serial can contain? will the extension of the serial be possible within max msp?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the OSC Protocol to communicate between the Arduino Mega and Max.
I use the library ardosc. There is no documentation on it but its not really hard to use it and it is a good library.

If you cannot use it do not hesitate to ask me some explanations